# Compare 3 columns and throw error if they match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to compare email, address to book selected.

What I want is if email + address = the book selected throw an error.

In other words, if the book selected is the same book selected previously then throw an error. That person cannot select the same book twice. That person can select multi books just not the same book.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE `emailaddress` = '{$emailaddress}' 
OR `mailaddress` = '{$mailaddress}' OR `bookselected` = '{$bookselected}' ";
```

I tried OR but if the same email or address is used it throws a validation error  no matter if it's a different book selected. Validation states you've previously entered.

I tried AND but when using that it bypasses the validation for some reason.

Can someone help with this sql statement?

Comment: Some real data example with expected result will be helpful.

Comment: You should use `AND`. What do you mean with "bypasses the validation"? You could also create a unique multicolumn index for the three columns. That way the database will throw an error were you to try to insert a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly your question, but if you are checking if a book has been already selected by a person with the same **emailaddress** and **mailaddress**, your query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE `emailaddress` = '{$emailaddress}'
AND `mailaddress` = '{$mailaddress}' AND `bookselected` = '{$bookselected}' ";
```

Notice the `AND` instead of the `OR`.

One thing you may have not mentioned is if you should be able to check **only** on one field between **mail** and **email**, in that case the query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE 
(`emailaddress` = '{$emailaddress}' AND `bookselected` = '{$bookselected}')
OR
(`mailaddress` = '{$mailaddress}' AND `bookselected` = '{$bookselected}') ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the second option also.  But the issue was a curly bracket the whole time.  As stated I used AND but it didn't work due to the bracket.  Since Francesco answered the question and gave me a second option, thanks for the help.

Comment: I do have a  question for Francesco.  Since this is a problem for everyone looking for help I've noticed, you made the comment "Not sure I understand correctly your question".  Can you explain what you couldn't understand?  Thanks

Comment: You say "I'm trying to compare email, address to book selected". Obviously an **email** and an **address** cannot be compared to a **book**, so you meant something different. After reading the whole answer I was able to figure it out correctly, but I had to guess a bit.